# How to set permanently separator sep to empty string in program R?

Tags: r, paste, cat, separator

There a few functions in R, that use variable sep, say:

```
cat("Hello","World\n", sep=" crazy ") # prints out: "Hello crazy World"
```

Do you know about any option that sets the sep variable to empty string in the whole R environment?

Obviously:

```
sep=""
cat("90","°") # does not work as expected and it prints out again: "90 °"
```

OK, I can write a wrapper, but I would prefer to set a global variable, if possible.
:-)

Edit:

I have found so far that I can redefine the standard functions, and so this way:

```
cat
```

prints out the definition of function, that I copied as a whole and just change sep=" " to sep="" in it:

```
cat <- function (..., file = "", sep = "", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL, append = FALSE) 
{
if (is.character(file)) 
if (file == "") 
file <- stdout()
else if (substring(file, 1L, 1L) == "|") { 
file <- pipe(substring(file, 2L), "w")
on.exit(close(file))
} else {
file <- file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))
on.exit(close(file))
}
.Internal(cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append))
}
```

Then it writes:

```
cat("Hello","World"); # "HelloWorld" as expected
```

OK, but I had to for all functions that uses the sep variable. A bit clumsy...

Comment: Why not use `paste0` ? `paste0("Hello","World\n")` .

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but cat0 does not work with this logic...

Comment: With your idea, those functions like `read.csv()` are also redefined as `sep = ""`. It's not convenient.

Comment: Then write a function called  `cat0() ` or `dog()` maybe and assign the separator as  `sep=""` in your default setting.

Comment: Even if you find out a way to set a global `sep`, you should not do it because you don't know how many functions it is going to effect. As mentioned by @DarrenTsai , you'll also change `read.csv`, there is also `sep` in `tidyr::separate` or `tidyr::separate_rows`. Do you really want all these functions to change their behavior?  Why do you want this? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The problem is my memory. I sometimes forget to add sep="" and this inconsistency makes my output awkward. I see that the simplest solution would be to write a wrapper: cat0 and use paste0...

Comment: To: Darren Tsai - You are right, so at least - how to change head of the given function without having copy all the body of the function. Say: cat <- function (..., file = "", sep = "", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL, append = FALSE) { keep_the original_definition() }